# What is an oracle separating IP and PSPACE?

Tags: complexity-theory, oracle-machines

I saw this link on cstheory:

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6634/is-there-an-oracle-that-separates-two-complexity-classes-known-to-be-equal

but it did not provide specific details.  Can anyone tell me what the specific oracle is (or direct me to a paper which does)?  Also on a meta-level why does this not call into question the legitimacy of oracle Turing machines- if two classes coincide, how can they be separated?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question you link contains all the information you need. The multi-authored paper [The random oracle hypothesis is false](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/papers/roh/roh.pdf) proves the stronger result that IP and PSPACE are different with probability 1 with respect to a *random* oracle. They also comment that a concrete oracle under which IP differs from PSPACE can be constructed using standard techniques, by which they mean the form of diagonalization used to separate P from NP with respect to a concrete oracle; they do not provide any details, though. Presumably it is a not too difficult exercise.

The meta-question is addressed both in the answer you link and in the paper. I suggest you first read the paper, and then if you have more questions, you can ask them here in this site.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry I guess I should have read the post more carefully.